# Is MySQL replication the right thing to use to set up a development environment for testing?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a website. I have a remote and local copy, and I develop on the local copy, and then when I've got a stable version I copy up all the PHP files and then I have to make the remote live MySQL database look like my local one.

I typically delete the remote, live database (as long as I'm not deleting new changes) and re-import it from a .sql file using PHPMyAdmin.

I want to set up a more reliable, correct, and idiot-proof, version updating system for my database. Is MySQL server replication the right answer? How is this usually done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you never want a development/test environment replicating to a live database. If you accidentally dropped a table, you'd wipe out the live site.

Better to use something like http://www.mysqldiff.org/

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the best way to do this is migrations. Migrations are essentially code which is stored with your application that update the database schema as it changes. The nice thing about migrations is that they can be versioned and it's easy to associate changes in the database schema with changes in the code. When used correctly, you can also use migrations to roll back the database to any previous state.

For an example, check out the use of migrations in the [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration).